# Ubuntu Installation on Toshiba Qosmio X770

Tags: installation

I am trying to install the last Ubuntu version on my laptop but I could not make it because the installation process freeze and don't let me go on. I got a Toshiba Qosmio X770 and I would like to use Ubuntu, but might be not compatible, please can you help me?

Comment: First things first, does it boot in live media mode?  If so, then it's an installer bug to troubleshoot.  If not, then it's more likely a compatibility issue...

Answer (score 0):

04 on the same set-up and found that removing the "quiet splash" from the grub boot configuration fixed the issue?

Not quite sure why..